# .htaccess issue just need to remove "/" from html pages

Tags: html, regex, apache, .htaccess, url

I hope I am writing this question at right place.
I also google my question or may I actually not exactly know how to google my problem.

I will little describe my issue it may help someone to understand.

I download html pages from a web server and these are in large number. In each html page in image or link there is "/" 
for examples

```
<img src="/newimage.jpg" /> and <a href="/myfile.html">file</a>
```

so when I need properly working I have to need to remove "/" from each img and a .

I also find that it has .htaccess file I think this thing can be handle from here but I am not pro in it and even not exactly know how make search query for my issue.
Please help me out if you can know anything about my issue.
Thanks in advance.

### **Update:**

I am sorry If I cannot elaborate my question properly.
I am giving you another example
In my html pages the the css path is give like this:

```
<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And it will not working for me I have to edit it and will make it like this

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

You can see that I only remove "/" from style.css and it will now working for me, in all html all urls are same like this.
I know this is .htaccess issue but not know how to search this or how to do this.

Comment: Can you please clear your question? You want to remove the slash("/") from each <img> and <a> tag? Or you want to make the <a> and <img> tag working? Also, please add the code of .htaccess file.

Comment: Thank  you for your kind reply , I have update my question I hope it will now easy to understand, what I want and what is my current issue.

Comment: because these links are working fine on server but not with me due to path issue! on my localhost

Comment: ¿How can those wrong links be identified under a URI perspective? There has to be a pattern to do what you want.

Comment: please what kind pattern?

Comment: How `/newimage.jpg`, for example, can be identified in the URL to require redirection, apart from the fact that it has a leading slash `/` in the file. I really don't think htacces is the way to solve that problem. Try adding the appropriate code to correct those links, in the script that downloads the files. There is one for sure.

Comment: Your only concern is to run your site on your localhost? Why don't you create a virtual host? So you could run your site under `http://mysite.localhost/` and then all your absolute URL paths will work again.

Comment: @unor I try this but I am not pro and not able to add subdomain to my localhost when I create subdomain to locahost when I try to call subdomain.localhost my browser open www.subdomain.localhost :)

Comment: @Naveed: If this would solve your problem, create a new question about how to create a virtual host.

Comment: @unor you were right my problem is solved by putting my code in subdomain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@unor give me idea to have a try for virtual host. After putting all my code in sub-domain it is now working perfectly. So the main issue was the code in main domain not .htaccess.

Thanks you all guys for help me out.